# Using ref with dynamic tag name in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that has a dynamic tag name which can be either `div` or `fieldset` depending on the value of the `group` prop that's returned from our `useForm` hook.

```
const FormGroup = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLFieldSetElement | HTMLDivElement,
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLFieldSetElement | HTMLDivElement>
>(({ children, className, ...props }, ref) => {
  const { group } = useForm();
  const Component = group ? "fieldset" : "div";

  return (
    <Component ref={ref} className={className} {...props}>
      {children}
    </Component>
  );
});
```

However it returns an error that `ref` is not assignable... I tried using:

```
const Component = group ? "fieldset" : "div" as keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;
```

Is there a clean way to type check a dynamic tag name that's using a ref?

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach

```
import {
  ElementType,
  FC,
  HTMLAttributes,
  Ref,
  forwardRef,
  useRef,
} from "react";

interface ComponentProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
  as?: ElementType;
  ref: Ref<HTMLElement>;
}

const Component: FC<ComponentProps> = forwardRef(
  ({ as: Tag = "div", children, ...otherProps }, ref) => {
    return (
      <Tag {...otherProps} ref={ref}>
        {children}
      </Tag>
    );
  }
);

const App: FC = () => {
  const myRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
  const group: "div" | "fieldset" = "div";
  return (
    <>
      <div>App</div>
      <Component as={group} ref={myRef}>
        <p>This is the component's content</p>
      </Component>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```